# SQL stored proc runs extremely slow when filtering by high row numbers

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures

This query is generated from a very long dynamic sequel stored procedure -- the procedure returns the requested number of records starting at a given index to be displayed in a Telerik Radgrid, effectively handling paging.  A simplified version of the stored proc's output:

```
SELECT r.* FROM (
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY InventoryId DESC) as row,
       v.* FROM vInventorySearch v
       ) as R WHERE [ROW] BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

When the "BETWEEN" clause is between 1 and 10, it runs in a fraction of a second, but if it's between something like 10000 and 1010 it takes almost a full minute to execute.

I feel like I may be missing something fundamental here, but it seems to me that it shouldn't matter which 10 records I'm retrieving, it should take the same amount of time.

Thanks for any input, I'm looking forward to being embarrassed!

---

Solution, courtesy Martin Smith (below) :

```
SELECT r.*, inv.* FROM 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY InventoryId DESC) as row, v.InventoryID
    FROM vInventorySearch v
    WHERE 1=1 
) as R 
inner join vInventory inv on r.InventoryID = inv.InventoryID
WHERE [ROW] BETWEEN 10001 AND 10010
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post your table definition including indexes and the execution plan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paginating by `ROW_NUMBER` can indeed be pretty inefficient for higher row numbers.

Sometimes it is better to break it up a bit and have the `ROW_NUMBER` query on a narrow index to retrieve the matching PKs with a join back onto the base table to retrieve the missing columns.

Comment: Thanks so much, Martin.  This is exactly what I ended up doing...query went from taking 45 seconds to a fraction of a second. Solution in post.

Comment: @DanielMyManiel - Glad it helped. I've seen `ROW_NUMBER` plans where it does thousands of unnecessary bookmark look ups to retrieve column values that never actually end up getting used as they are only required for the 10 rows or so that match the filter. I guess in your case `vInventorySearch` is likely a view so maybe it was performing something even more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

SQL 2012 has more efficient paging mechanism

http://stevestedman.com/2012/04/tsql-2012-offset-and-fetch/

SELECT DepartmentID, Revenue, Year 
FROM REVENUE 
ORDER BY Year, DepartmentID ASC 
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll have to check it out.  Right now I'm working with SQL 2008 but will keep this in mind for the next project.